# post_save signal for specific Profile model for user registration

Tags: django, save, signals, multiple-users

I have 2 profile models (Profile1 and Profile 2) with a one-to-one relationship with the django User class. I have 2 separate registration forms, 2 different signals, 2 different views / routes for each model. When I register a user with Profile1, it creates the Profile1 instance but it also creates a Profile2 instance. How can I specify the signal to use based on the type of user signing up?

Here is my signals.py for Profile1

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile1(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile1.objects.create(customer=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile1(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    instance.profile1.save()
```

Here is my signals.py for Profile2

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile2(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile2.objects.create(customer=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile2(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    instance.profile2.save()
```

Below are the 2 views from separate view files

```
# view for registration of Profile1
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        p_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            user = u_form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db() 
            p_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST,
                                       instance=user.profile1)  
            p_form.full_clean()  
            p_form.save() 

            messages.success(request, 'Your account has been created!')
            return redirect('profile1_login')
    else:
        u_form = RegisterForm()
        p_form = ProfileRegisterForm()

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'profile1/register.html', context)


# view for registration of Profile2 
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        p_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            user = u_form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  
            p_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST,
                                                 instance=user.profile2)  
            p_form.full_clean()  )
            p_form.save() 

            messages.success(request, 'Your account has been created!')
            return redirect('profile2_login')
    else:
        u_form = RegisterForm()
        p_form = ProfileRegisterForm()

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'profile2/register.html', context)
```

Comment: You either have to create the intended Profile(1 or 2) where you are creating the User object or there has to be some parameter which let's you know which field of User model defines which Profile to create,  both the signals are working as expected. You need to be clear about how two profiles differ from each other.

Comment: @danish_wani so how do I do this? How can I check in my signals if it is intended for Profile1 or Profile2

Comment: See you are doing it wrong, if you have two different registration forms for profile 1 and 2, why don&#39;t you create the respective profile in their respective views? Kindly add both the views and forms to your question

Comment: @danish_wani above are my views file

Comment: what is the difference between profile1 and profile2? the two registration methods are similar except they redirect to two different urls.  and as far as RegisterForm and ProfileRegisterForm they seems to be respective forms for User and Profile creation am i right? If so, then why do you need signals if you are already creating both the instances

Comment: I have 2 different types of users. They share the same fields for the default user and they have other fields that are unique to them.

Comment: so what exactly are you trying to achieve here? if you already able to create users and userprofiles ? why are using signals?

Comment: The signals are the ones that are creating the profiles. If user registers for Profile 1 route, then I want to create a profile1 instance only. Same goes for profile2

Comment: are RegisterForm and ProfileRegisterForm ModelForms?

Comment: RegisterForm is a UserCreationForm while ProfileRegisterForm is a ModelForm

Answer (score 1):

the `sender` parameter in the receiver is `User` model so every time that the Profile1 or Profile2 is created that means the `User` is created too, so both of the signals is called.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile1)
def create_profile1(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile1.objects.create(customer=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile1)
def save_profile1(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    instance.profile1.save()


@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile2)
def create_profile2(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile2.objects.create(customer=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Profile2)
def save_profile2(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    instance.profile2.save()
```

Comment: So how do I fix this?

Comment: Why you use save_profile1() and save_profile2()??? create_profile1() and create_profile2() not enough???

Answer (score 0):

So this one worked. I just created the instance inside the view and passed it to the form.

```
# view for registration of Profile1
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        p_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            user = u_form.save()

            # ==================CHANGES MADE=====================
            # get fields
            field1 = p_form.cleaned_data.get('field1')

            profile = Profile1Model.objects.create(field1 = field1, ...)

            p_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST,
                                       instance=profile)
            #=====================================================                         

            p_form.save()
```